# Python: Unique Value Count in a Pivot Table from a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I will like to create a pivot table that breaks out `amount` (which  I did) and count of `uniqueID` breakdown by Month .. the last part `uniqueID` is that I'm struggling with.

I have the following data frame with colums:
`['Agent', 'Player', 'Amount', 'Month', 'UniqueID']`

I was able to do the following:

Trying to get the count for UniqueID:

```py
df['UniqueID']= df['UniqueID'].map(df['UniqueID'].value_counts())
```

I also tried -

```py
df['UniqueID'] =len(set(df['UniqueID'])
```

Succesfully created my pivot table

```py
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Agent','Player'], margins=True, margins_name='Total', columns=['Month'], values =['Amount','UniqueID'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

However the total I get for `UniqueID` is not accurrate.
I am trying to get count of `UniqueID` per month in my pivot.
Any help will be greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please include a sample of `df`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with `aggfunc` of `nunique` for `UniqueID` instead of `sum`:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Agent', 'Player'], margins=True,
                    margins_name='Total', columns=['Month'],
                    values=['Amount', 'UniqueID'],
                    aggfunc={'Amount': 'sum', 'UniqueID': 'nunique'})
```

`nunique` will get the count of unique values per grouping.

```
             Amount                  UniqueID                
Month             1    2     3 Total        1    2    3 Total
Agent Player                                                 
A     C         3.0  NaN   NaN     3      1.0  NaN  NaN     1  # nunique is 1
      D         NaN  3.0   NaN     3      NaN  1.0  NaN     1
B     D         NaN  4.0   NaN     4      NaN  1.0  NaN     1
      E         NaN  NaN   5.0     5      NaN  NaN  1.0     1
      F         NaN  NaN   6.0     6      NaN  NaN  1.0     1
Total           3.0  7.0  11.0    21      1.0  2.0  2.0     5
```

Could also use `count` if wanted count of all `UniqueID`s

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Agent', 'Player'], margins=True,
                    margins_name='Total', columns=['Month'],
                    values=['Amount', 'UniqueID'],
                    aggfunc={'Amount': 'sum', 'UniqueID': 'count'})
```

```
             Amount                  UniqueID                
Month             1    2     3 Total        1    2    3 Total
Agent Player                                                 
A     C         3.0  NaN   NaN     3      2.0  NaN  NaN     2  # count is 2
      D         NaN  3.0   NaN     3      NaN  1.0  NaN     1
B     D         NaN  4.0   NaN     4      NaN  1.0  NaN     1
      E         NaN  NaN   5.0     5      NaN  NaN  1.0     1
      F         NaN  NaN   6.0     6      NaN  NaN  1.0     1
Total           3.0  7.0  11.0    21      2.0  2.0  2.0     6
```

---

Sample Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Agent': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Player': ['C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'Amount': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Month': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'UniqueID': [15, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23]
})
```

`df`:

```
  Agent Player  Amount  Month  UniqueID
0     A      C       1      1        15
1     A      C       2      1        15
2     A      D       3      2        20
3     B      D       4      2        21
4     B      E       5      3        22
5     B      F       6      3        23
```